# Can Azure DHCP service be disabled?

Tags: azure, dhcp

I want to control a DHCP service from a VM with dedicated network interface. (install the DHCP role)
I can't find where to turn of azure native dhcp off, anyone know how to do that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot turn off Azure DHCP and so you cannot host your own DHCP server.